# How to remove empty field after matching data?

Tags: php

I have created a database and and its tables. Insertion has done successfully. Now I want to get data from two tables using left join.

The problem is some fields which are not matching are empty. I want to remove the empty fields and to show the matching fields data.

How can I do this?

My code is:

```
<?php
    
    include 'connection.php';
    
    //joining of two table column
    $sql = "select * from oc4e_product left join item ON item.Description =            oc4e_product.model";
           
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<table border = 1px>";
    echo "<tr>
            <th>S/No</th>
            <th>Web Name</th><th>POS Name</th> <th>POS Name</th></tr>";
    $i=1;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td>
                    <td>".$row['model'] ."</td>
                    <td>". $row['Description'] . "</td>
                </tr>";
                  
            $i++;
        }
    }
                
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What empty field?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have created a database and and its tables. insertion has done successfully. now i want to get data from two tables using left join. the problem is some fields which are not matching shown empty to me. i want to remove the empty fields and to show the matching fields data. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to modify your sql query:

```
 //joining of two table column
    $sql = "select * from oc4e_product left join item ON item.Description = oc4e_product.model where item.Description <> ''";
```

In this query i added filter not empty record `item.Description <> ''`

Comment: "Maybe" might be a good start, but it would be even better if you added some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it